# How access a attribute from a Object dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

In my object

```
obj.resposta1
obj.resposta2
obj.resposta3
obj.resposta4
```

how access the values of each inside a

> for ( var int = 1; int < 5; int++)

?

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
    alert(obj['resposta' + i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for ( var int = 1; int < 5; int++){
    obj['resposta'+int];
}
```

Comment: `int` isn't exactly a good choice of variable name, since it's easily confused with other languages where it's a keyword.

Comment: @Neil: Totally agree! Just gave an answer based on the given code. I didn't validate the code, neither did I show an example of what to do with the object, once it has been accessed, just showed the way to access it.